# Keycloak authentication problems when using docker and java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, keycloak

So I have a spring boot application. I also use swagger for testing purposes. 
I have a keycloak defined inside docker-compose like this:

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
    volumes:
        - ../keycloak:/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports
    command: 
        - "-b 0.0.0.0 -Dkeycloak.import=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/realm-export.json"
    environment:
        - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
        - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
```

when I try to run my spring boot application I use `http://localhost:18080/auth` as `keycloak_auth_url`. When running from my machine everything works.
When running through docker-compose I change keycloak url to: `http://keycloak:18080/auth`
but the url that swaggers uses for redirecting user to keycloak stays the same `http://localhost:18080/auth`

Authenticating through swaggers "works". But when I try to call an API endpoint as authenticated user my server returns the following error:

```
Error when sending request to retrieve realm keys
myApp  | 
myApp  | org.keycloak.adapters.HttpClientAdapterException: IO error
```

```
Didn't find publicKey for kid: U7a58q_oR3zXWSAwVUIa_7FvhdA7IncCQ2IfKQKDGfI
myApp  | 2020-01-07 11:58:40.615 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
```

Now I am not sure is the problem that my app cannot connect to keycloak to check token. or did checking of token fail?
thanks for all the help

Comment: did you also change the auth-url in your spring-service applicaiton properties? Didn't find public key is a sign that your service can't get the code ( public-key) of keycloak becuase the url is wrong

Comment: yes I changed it to: 
`http://keycloak:18080/auth` I persume docker networking substitues keycloak part with the IP. I did the same with database and database connects sucesfully, but keycloak fails

Comment: it should be `http://keycloak:8080/auth` because `8080` is for container and `18080` is exposed to host.

Comment: makes sense now... so if i wanted container to use 18080 I just change docker compose to: 18080:18080 ?

Comment: Only if the app in the container really runs on `18080` port. But keycloak is run on the 8080 port by default I assume. So you would have to change it's (keycloak) configuration to run on 18080 also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to change the `keycloak_auth_url` to `http://keycloak:8080/auth` (if you are using spring-boot you could do it using environment variable instead of hardcoding it) if you want to connect to it from other container that is set up by compose.

The `8080` port is the port that the keycloack is running on in the keycloak container and `18080` port is the port that is published to the `host`.

Comment: Correct. It helps to think in networks. To get the code to verify the token the spring service will call auth url inside the docker networks without leaving the network. So because you are not requesting from the host you have to use the docker internal url.

Comment: This answer really helped me find a solution and better help me understand what exactly I was doing wrong. Thank you!